# how can I call two variables from a class of another script (tkinter) so they are inputs of my main .py?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I have two scripts, one is the main.py and the other has a class that has a TKinter IU. From the TKinter, it should get some variables, and those variables should be the input for the main.py

How can I make this possible?

I've tried to do this, but it's only my second day with tkinter libreries and don't know much about clases.

this is the supertrend02_tk.py(tkinter)

```
import config
from binance.client import Client 
from binance.enums import *
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import Calendar
import tkinter as tk

client = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET, tld='com')

exchange_info = client.get_exchange_info()


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack() # Window is packed in its master.

        exitButton = Button(self, text="1st Run this", command=self.clickrunButton)
        exitButton.pack()

    def clickrunButton(self):
        self.run() # Now this work



    def run(self):
        def get_info():
            data=[]
            for s in exchange_info['symbols']:
                print(s['symbol'])
                data.append(s['symbol'])
            info_recibida = data
            
            return info_recibida

        OPTIONS = get_info()
        
        def on_change_selection(value):
            print('   value:', value)
            print('selected:', selected.get())

        master = Tk(className='SuperTrend Backtesting Bot')

        selected = tk.StringVar(master)
        selected.set(OPTIONS[0])

        w = OptionMenu(master, selected, *OPTIONS, command=on_change_selection)

        # set window size
        master.geometry("500x500")

        #master.mainloop() 
        ####################################################
        # Add Calendar
        cal = Calendar(master, selectmode = 'day',
                    year = 2022, month = 11,
                    day = 13)
        
        cal.pack(pady = 20)
        
        def grad_date():
            date.config(text = "Selected Date is: " + cal.get_date())
        
        # Add Button and Label
        Button(root, text = "Get Date",
            command = grad_date).pack(pady = 20)

        date = Label(root, text = "")
        
        dia_inicial = cal.get_date()

        date.pack(pady = 20)

        w.pack()



root = Tk()
app = Window(root)

# set window title
root.wm_title("Supertrend")

# show window
root.mainloop()
```

and the variables that I should use in the main.py are:

```
    from binance.client import Client 
    
    from tkinter import *
    from tkcalendar import Calendar
    import tkinter as tk
    client = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET, tld='com')
    
    exchange_info = client.get_exchange_info()
    import supertrend02_tk
    from supertrend02_tk import dia_inicial, selected
    
    plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20,10)
    
    print("cara_bobo")
    symbolo=selected
print(symbolo)
    idate=dia_inicial
print(idate)
```

Comment: Don't name your script as `tkinter.py` because it will override the `tkinter` module.  Also it is better to post `main.py` in order to provide a [mre].

Comment: like this? an can't post more from the main.py

Comment: @acw1668 . Please help, I'm stuck with this